# Word for counting number of kids

Tags: склонение, числительные

I know that, in order to tell "people" (plural) with no numerals, we must say **люди**. **Человек** is used either for singular with no numeral, or for plural with numerals. Consequently, 2/3/4 is followed by **человека**, whereas from 5 upward it's once again **человек**, a kind of irregular genitive plural with null ending (like the words *волос*, *сапог*, *грузин*).

Like the word for person/people, the word for "kid" features two different roots, either for no-numeral plural (**дети**, not counting the expression *трое детей*) and for singular (**ребёнок**).

That said, which word should be used when trying to attach a numeral to the idea of "kid"?

2 kids - два ребёнка?

5 kids - пять ребёнок?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special cases for number of kids `1`-`4`:

1. `Один ребёнок`.
2. `Два ребёнка` / `двое детей`.
3. `Три ребёнка` / `трое детей`.
4. `Четыре ребёнка` / `четверо детей`.

For number of kids `5`-`10`:

5. `Пять (пятеро) детей`.
6. `Шесть (шестеро) детей`.
   ...

For number of kids ending with `1`-`4` if number of tens is not equal to `1`:

21. `Двадцать один ребёнок`.
22. `Двадцать два ребёнка`.
23. `Двадцать три ребёнка`.
24. `Двадцать четыре ребёнка`.

And so on for (31-34, 41-44, ..., 101-104, 121-124, ...).

For all other number of kids:

`5. Пять детей`.
`6. Шесть детей`.
`36. Тридцать шесть детей`.
`128. Сто двадцать восемь детей`.

and so on.

Comment: And now the same for all grammatical cases please ;)

Comment: When saying "У меня X детей" ('I have X number of kids') it is more common to use двое, трое, четверо детей rather than два, три, четыре ребенка.

Comment: Those numerals ending in 1-4 exclude 11, 12, 13 and 14, which take the genitive plural, right?

Comment: @swrutra Yep, 11-14, 111-114, ... are the case "all other number of kids".

Comment: Additionally, when collective numerals are used, then one would use *"пятеро ребят / пятеро детей".*